# How do I safely hook into the message pump from a DLL?

Tags: c++, windows

I'm trying to get messages from the process that loaded my DLL.

I've tried:

```
SetWindowsHookEx(WH_CALLWNDPROC, (HOOKPROC)WndProc, hInstance, 0);
```

Which gives me error popups about how "Program X could not be started because Y.dll is missing from your system".  This is the reason I put "safely" in the title.

I've also tried:

```
SetWindowsHookEx(WH_CALLWNDPROC, (HOOKPROC)WndProc, hInstance, threadId);
```

Where `threadId` is the result of `GetCurrentThreadId()` in my DLLMain.
This one works, but I don't get any messages for the window (just a bunch of 512 and 1025).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Messages are related to threads and windows, your DLL might be loaded by processes. So there is no direct correspondence.

Hooks on the other hand are either global or per-thread.

All together this means that you have to choose whether you want messages just from specific threads, or global (all threads in all processes in specific desktop) where you will filter out the process of your interest yourself.

Your second code snippet is a thread hook. The first one is the global hook where you definitely do something wrong as successful hook itself does not cause error messages you mentioned.

Comment: Thank you, this answered a lot of my questions.  I'm using the wintab library which wants a `hwnd` to pass messages to.  Do threads have a hierarchy I can climb to find the nearest one with a window associated, or should I create a hidden window in my DLL?

Comment: If you are doing this complicated stuff just for a window handle, then definitely do not hook somebody's property. Create your own instead. Note however that your window has to be on a thread with a message loop. So if you are lucky enough, you will just create a window; otherwise you will need to create a background thread with window there and a message loop. In any event, both are way easier and more reliable to hooking.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing that you are calling these functions directly from inside DLLMain.  There are serious limitations on which functions you can safely call from DLLMain, see the [MSDN documentation on DLLMain](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682583%28VS.85%29.aspx) about this.

There is no explicit list of safe and unsafe functions, but it seems likely that the call to SetWindowsHookEx in your first code fragment is doing something that is forbidden in a DLLMain function, hence the failure for the DLL to load properly.

Comment: Actually I'm using `CreateThread` in DLLMain, and then calling this code in the callback.  After that I have a basic message loop.  Sorry, I should have clarified that.

Comment: I wanted to say that you couldn't safely call CreateThread in DLLMain, but after a bit of research I've drawn the conclusion that you can, although it isn't recommended. :-)

Comment: In this case, the call to SetWindowsHookEx in your first sample almost certainly never even ran; the "missing DLL" error should have caused the process to terminate before your new thread had a chance to run.  Perhaps you were inadvertently returning 0 from DLLMain?

Comment: To clarify: the message loop isn't inside DLLMain either, right?